# Swift - UICollectionView removeAll() temporarily clears the cells

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am dynamically adding data to the UICollectionView. Whenever I have a new data it clears all the existing data and loads a new set. Here is the code,

```
self.conversation.removeAll()
self.collectionView.reloadData()

self.conversation.insert(messageWrapper(description: "Some text", origin: "user"), at: 0)
self.collectionView.reloadData()
```

Code in `ItemAtIndexPath`

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        let textViewCell = cell as! TextCollectionViewCell
        let description = conversation[indexPath.row].description
        let origin = conversation[indexPath.row].origin

        textViewCell.textView.text = description
        textViewCell.textView.textAlignment = origin == "arvis" ? NSTextAlignment.left : NSTextAlignment.right
    }
```

**Problem** It removes all the existing data and while loading new data, it overlaps with the previous data i.e., let's say if I have `Hello` and while adding `I am good`, it displays `Hello` and 'I am good` on top of it.

[image]

Why does this happens?

**UPDATE 1:** 
**cellForItemAt**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let textViewCell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "textViewCell", for: indexPath) as! TextCollectionViewCell
        let description = conversation[indexPath.row].description
        let origin = conversation[indexPath.row].origin

        textViewCell.awakeFromNib()
        textViewCell.textView.text = description
        textViewCell.textView.textAlignment = origin == "arvis" ? NSTextAlignment.left : NSTextAlignment.right

        return textViewCell
    }
```

**TextCollectionViewCell** 
Identifier class for the cell

```
class TextCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    var textView: UITextView!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        textView = UITextView(frame: contentView.frame)
        textView.textColor = UIColor.white
        textView.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18)
        textView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        textView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        textView.clipsToBounds = true
        contentView.addSubview(textView)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The existing data gets cleared because you are clearing the datasource of the collectionView and reloading it.

Just try appending the new value to `conversation` array and then reloading the collectionView.

If the issue is with overalapping just try updating `textViewCell.textView` from `cellForItemAtIndexPath` instead of updating `textViewCell.textView` in `willDisplaycell`

Comment: Yes, right! I want to clear all the existing data, which works fine! But the problem is that it appears again while loading new data to the conversation.

Comment: Could you please post the code for cellForItemAtIndexPath

Comment: @aravindtrue instead of updating `textViewCell.textView` in `willDisplaycell` try updating `textViewCell.textView` from cellForItemAtIndexPath and check

Comment: @AravindAR, Looks like, it's not working! I have added my code under `UPDATE 1` section

Comment: @aravindtrue try adding textViewCell.textView.text = nil above textViewCell.textView.text = description and see whether it works ?

Comment: @AravindAR I tried it already, it didn't work! I've changed the UITextView to UILabel and everything works fine. I am really not sure, what is the problem.

Comment: @aravindtrue ohh okk happy that your problem is solved :)

Answer (score 0):

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let textViewCell = cell as! TextCollectionViewCell

    let description = conversation[indexPath.row].description
        let origin = conversation[indexPath.row].origin

        textViewCell.textView.text = description
        textViewCell.textView.textAlignment = origin == "arvis" ? NSTextAlignment.left : NSTextAlignment.right

    return textViewCell
}
```

try this instead of updating in `willDisplay cell:` use `cellForItemAt indexPath:`